# call @classmethod from another @classmethod of another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method

I have two python files as

**one.py**

```
class FirstClass:
    @classmethod
    def myClass(cls,first, second):
        return first+second
```

**two.py**

```
from one import FirstClass

class SecondClass:
    @classmethod
    def herClass(cls, val1, val2):
        FirstClass.myClass(val1,val2)

ob = SecondClass()
print(ob.herClass(2,3))
```

How can I access the classmethod of one class from the classmethod of another class. If not possible, what might be the possible solution. FirstClass needs to remain same, I have flexibility changing the method type on SecondClass.

Comment: Since, In myClass method, you are not using cls, So it is better to define it as a staticmethod.

Comment: ...or even as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you're missing the return of this function

```
def herClass(cls, val1, val2):
        return FirstClass.myClass(val1,val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation just add `return` statement in `SecondClass.herClass`

Corrected code will look like this

```
class SecondClass:
    @classmethod
    def herClass(cls, val1, val2):
        return FirstClass.myClass(val1,val2)
```